# Google Pay Direct Integration Rotation of keys

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay, cybersource, adyen

I am trying to implement the Google Pay using direct integration and in the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#key-rotation) it is mentioned that merchants have to manually rotate the keys. During rotation it is mentioned that
**Caution: You must support the old private key for decryption of payment methods for eight days after you remove the old public key.**

Does this mean I need to support old private key even after deleting the old public key?

I found out that Google uses Elliptic Curve Digital Signature which is asymmetric. As far as I know in case of asymmetric algorithms only one key pair will be involved (public and private). Why does Google recommend to support old private key up to 8 days?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is the following:

- define/upload a new key pair (recommended annually)
- support both new and old keys during decryption

  ```
   String decryptedMessage =
    new PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.Builder()
       .addRecipientPrivateKey(newPrivateKey)
       .addRecipientPrivateKey(oldPrivateKey);
  ```
- remove old key

This is a common approach as the platform might require some time to propagate the new keys and make sure the old ones are no longer used. **You need to support the old key** deploying the code above (supporting both signatures) for some time (at least 8 days according to Google's note) and ideally

> confirm that the old public key is no longer used to encrypt any
> transactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Beppe C. Once I generate the new key pair and add the new public key in business console, does this mean even though If I send the new public key as part of payment request from the client side, still Google may use the old public key for encryption so that's why I need to support for old private key for up to 8 days?. Please explain this point.

Comment: Payment data should be encrypted with a new public key, however it is possible that the previous key is still in use (for a lapse of time), hence must be able to support both for a period of time